# PHP time difference not working for 24 hours

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate the difference in time between two times using this:

```
round(abs(strtotime("17:30") - strtotime("18:30")) / 60,2);

= '1'
```

which works fine, but as soon as i make it over 2 days its not calculating correctly

```
round(abs(strtotime("17:30") - strtotime("02:00")) / 60,2);

= '15.5' this should be '8.5'
```

Comment: You should use the date too, not only hours minutes. Example 29:02:00 - 28:17:30 = 8:30

Comment: You might want it to be 8.5 but it rightfully is 15.5 . The problem is that by calculating the absolute value you disregard the order of things. if you were to calculate it as end - start, you could have noticed the negative result that indicates essentially an overflow. Better to add dates to avoid that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime` returns an timestamp. Currently your calculation is only partly correct, because you ignore negative values. In case of negative values (that should be the case, if the second time is on the next day), you should add `86400` (24*60*60 - the seconds of a day).

```
$start = strtotime("17:30");
$end = strtotime("02:00");
$diff = $end - $start;
// end date is on the next day
if ($diff < 0) {
    $diff += 86400;
}
$hours = $diff / 3600;
echo round($hours, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

For more accurate and correct results you can use [*->diff()*](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) function. As an example:

```
<?php
$val1 = '2014-03-18 10:34:09.939';
$val2 = '2014-03-14 10:34:09.940';

$datetime1 = new DateTime($val1);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($val2);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

**Output**:

```
-4 days
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the math yourself by converting dates into unixtime:

```
strtotime('2017-12-29 02:00')-strtotime('2017-12-28 17:30')
```

This will return the difference in seconds, so if I want to print the value in hours, I have to divide by 60 twice:

```
php > print((strtotime('2017-12-29 02:00')-strtotime('2017-12-28 17:30'))/60/60);
8.5
```